# How to make a Reddit account without "instant shadowban"?

Tags: reddit

Every time I try to create a Reddit account, as soon as I make a post or comment the account is immediately shadowbanned. I have tried many combinations of clearing cookies, using different browsers, different devices, and different Internet connections, verified email address or no email address. One thing I haven't tried is using the Reddit mobile app, because it sucks.

I can see this because if I load my profile page from a different browser before trying to comment, it says the user hasn't posted anything. If I refresh the page after trying to comment, it says the user doesn't exist. That's how shadowbans behave.

It feels like Reddit is trying to make it impossible for anyone to make new accounts due to some extreme anti-spam measure. The reason I think this is the result of some extreme anti-spam measure is that it still happens when I create an account that shouldn't be traceable to me in any way (IP address, cookies, fingerprints, time of day, email address).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150815/discussion-on-question-by-user253751-how-to-make-a-reddit-account-without-insta); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't create a new account to avoid being shadowbanned. In fact, that will cause those new accounts to be shadowbanned too, as it violates the [Reddit Content Policy](https://www.redditinc.com/policies/content-policy). Instead, you should [appeal your shadowban](https://www.reddit.com/appeals) (at https://www.reddit.com/appeals) — to the Reddit admins, who are staff of Reddit, not the volunteer moderators of each subreddit.

See this Reddit support article: "[My account is caught in the spam filter](https://support.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045309012-My-account-is-caught-in-the-spam-filter)" for more information on how to appeal your shadowban.

> If a moderator refers you to the admins or suggests you are “shadowbanned,” your account might have tripped the spam filter. This may explain why your posts and comments aren’t showing up as expected or why other users do not receive your messages.
>
> #### I think my account is caught in the spam filter
>
> 1. Open a browser window and log into the affected account.
> 2. Navigate to https://www.reddit.com/appeals

Comment: This would be a correct answer if appeals ever did anything for anyone. They seem to be sent to /dev/null.

Comment: @user253751 Unfortunately, once Reddit finds out that you created a new account to evade a ban, the new account will also be banned.

Comment: I don't think that applies to shadowbans. Since Reddit doesn't acknowledge that shadowbans even exist, they also don't say you can't evade one, or that you can appeal it. I know that in the past, you could create a new account nearly identical to a shadowbanned one, and nothing would happen.

Comment: @user253751 The support article I mentioned above says Reddit acknowledges shadowbans. Since the content policy says you must not evade a ban, we can infer that the same applies to shadowbans.

Comment: @user253751 When did you appeal your shadowban, by the way? It might be that Reddit staff aren't currently processing ban appeals due to the holiday season.

Comment: @galacticninja to be clear the policy talks about being banned, not shadow banned. The OP also didn't indicate that a mod advised them that they were  "shadowbanned" (emphasis from Reddit post).  It's all really moot. Problem with account? Contact Reddit. Wanna know how they are detecting you? We can't answer that. Wanna have a discussion about Reddit policy? Nothing wrong with that except this is not the place.

Comment: @Blindspots OP’s situation matches the definition of shadowbanning on Reddit. According to the Reddit support article I referenced, shadowbanned users’ posts and comments won’t show up as expected, and other users will not receive their messages. On the other hand, if a user is banned or suspended (not shadowbanned), they will be notified of their status, which is not the case for OP. Due to how it works, a shadowban is effectively the same as a ban, except that you're not notified of the ban. If the OP raises this issue with a Reddit mod, they will advise OP that they're shadowbanned.

Comment: @galacticninja I don't disagree with your most recent comment.